# How to disable default alt-left / alt-right keyboard shortcuts for Numbers.app

Tags: keyboard, numbers

I'm continually hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to move navigate within a cell in Numbers, and inadvertently inserting new rows.. How can I disable all the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> shortcuts?

I've tried changing the Application specific keys in System Prefs > Keyboard, and my new keys work, but the old remain active.  Is there a tidy oneliner to paste into the terminal?!

**Edit:**

Hmm.. I can't replicate the problem that I'm asking about! ATM when I  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> into a cell to edit, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> is not adding a column!  Maybe I'm mashing some other keys in there intermittently?

BTW, I've also tried setting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left Arrow</kbd> to `Bring All Windows to Front` but that disabled using <kbd>Alt</kbd> whilst editing the cell.

Comment: bonus points for achieving this in any app!

Comment: The alt-right is dangerous indeed. And the alt-left...who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a quick look at this in Numbers.app 4.0.5, and I've found that by overriding the default keyboard shortcuts, the problematic behaviour is resolved.

Now if I hit <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> to edit the cell contents, I can hit <kbd>Alt+Right</kbd> and <kbd>Alt+Left</kbd> to navigate the text without adding any new columns (holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> to select text works fine, too).

The relevant menu items to override are:

- `Add Column Before`
- `Add Column After`

Docs: [macOS Sierra: Create keyboard shortcuts for apps](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25377?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US)

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: I someone else verifies that this works for them on OSX 10.12, Numbers.app 4.0.5 then I'll accept the answer...

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the plist directly:

`defaults write com.apple.iWork.Numbers NSUserKeyEquivalents '{"Add Column Before"="\0";"Add Column After"="\0";}'`

It overwrites custom shortcuts set in System Preferences, but you could also edit the plist in a text editor after converting it to XML:

```
plutil -convert xml1 ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork.Numbers.plist
```

Comment: fantastic!! exactly what i was hoping for!  If I edit the plist in xcode, what type of value should I  enter for the key? I've tried string(\0) and bool(NO) with no luck…

Comment: Escape sequences like `\0` only work in old-style property lists. You can use `&#0;` in an XML plist or a literal NUL character in Xcode's property list editor.

Comment: hmm.. feeling dense! not sure how to enter a NUL literal into the plist via xcode.. I am: opening the plist, adding a key 'Add Column After' (string) then I've tried a couple of options: empty string, Ctrl-Shift-2, 'NULL', then opening numbers hoping that Add Column After will no longer work.. what am i missing? tx :)

Comment: You can use `printf %b '\0'|pbcopy` or drag it from the Unicode view in CharacterPalette.

Comment: sorry, Lauri, this looks really promising, but I haven't been able to get it to work in Numers'09 v2.3(554) on 10.8.3… I've tried pasting the `defaults write` into terminal, and pasting the result of `printf %b '\0'|pbcopy` & also dragging the NUL character into xcode… but no dice! each time, i'm ensuring that numbers is closed, and saving the plist before opening numbers… could you confirm the version of numbers this is working for? tx for yr persistence!

Comment: Apparently it doesn't work for disabling ⌥← and ⌥→ in Numbers. This method does work with most shortcuts that have menu items though.